# Find the angles in a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$ if angle $B>C$ and both $B$ and $C$ satisfy $3\tan x-\tan^3x=k\sec^3x,(0<k<1)$ then angle A is

Comment: Welcome to math.SE.  Can you show your efforts and where you are stuck ?

Comment: $$k=3\sin x\cos^2x-\sin^3x=3\sin x(1-\sin^2x)-\sin^3x=\sin3x$$

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{3sinx}{cosx}- \frac{sin^3x}{cos^3x}= \frac{k}{cos^3x}$

$3sinx.cos^2x-sin^3x=k$

$sin3x=k$

i.e. $sin3B=sinC$

$3B= \pi-3C$

$B+C= \pi/3$

i.e. $A=2\pi/3$